# Mass hanging from vertical spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, harmonic-oscillator

Why does a mass hanging from an ideal spring, under gravity, undergo periodic oscillations? Isn't gravity a damping force here? Equation for mass spring system is given by $m\ddot{y}+ky=0$ where symbols have usual meanings.

Comment: Gravity is a conservative force in classical mechanics, so the potential energy you gain when going up is exactly the amount you get back when going down. There is no dampening from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gravitational force is a pulling force, not a damping force. It pulls down the mass to a new equilibrium position $x_0 = \frac{mg}{k}$. The mass then oscillate about the new equilibrium position.

Starting from the equation of motion:
$$
   m \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = -k y - mg.
$$

Change variable $\eta(t) = y(t) + \frac{mg}{k}$, which don't affect the second derivative. Therefore
\begin{align*}
   m \frac{d^2 \eta}{dt^2} &= -k \left( \eta - \frac{mg}{k}\right) - mg.\\
& = -k \eta.\\
  m \frac{d^2 \eta}{dt^2} + k \eta &= 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a damping force is that it *always* acts opposite to an object's velocity. When the mass is moving downwards, the object's weight acts with the object's velocity. Therefore, weight *cannot* be classified as a damping force.